# ufw issue. I can't deploy from Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I coundn't deploy from Laravel Forge when I set ufw like below.

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         LIMIT       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)
```

I need security measures and I don't want to change the ufw setting every deploy. I suppose I can set up whitelist if I can see IPs. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Update

It works if I remove "limit" setting but I need to avoid DOS attack.

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: What's the question here? Didn't get that.

Comment: I'm sorry my question is not clear. Laravel Forge is a paas service. Laravel Forge does not work when I have ufw setting. I need to find solutions.

Comment: Does laravel forge not have a support site? Better ask them.